# Will ARM replace that older processor architecture?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, microprocessor

I know that those processors with ARM architecture have their advantages, but will it replace those old kind of ones? Or they just will be dealing with different kinds of applications and continue to live?

Edit: I am not seeking a fotrune teller. I just needed someone who knows it to describe what is going on right now? How does it seem to go?

Comment: If you figure it out, let me know. I'll tell my financial advisor.

Comment: This is such a vague question that is more about future speculation than engineering.  The unfortunate answer is that, regardless of how awesome the technology is, marketing will come along and make it sink or swim.

Comment: One thing to remember is if someone comes out with an ARM chip that costs ten cents and runs for a year on a coin cell, someone else will want to use the same manufacturing processes to make a two cent chip that runs five years using a 8-bit CPU to save power/cost.

Comment: If I may, I can't see it like a blind man. When you say "we don't know" that is also an answer for me.That means it is not taking a rush like I am imagining. Or you can guess, and give a chance, but I am far less capable doing a such thing. So every comment and answer is just fine. Go ahead down vote, I am not a fan of upvotes.

Comment: @Zgrkpnr__ the reason for downvotes is because "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" which is very accurate for your question. It is also off topic, as it's not about electronics design. AND It's opinion based. These are all examples of terrible questions which clutter EE.SE. These sorts of questions could be asked in the EE.SE Chat, for example, and you'd get a reasonable and less negative response. My response: Until the old dinosaur designers go away, 8-Bit will remain for a while. ARM is already used in a huge amount of devices. It will take a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes a *long* time for an architecture to die.

The 8-bit instruction sets aren't even dead. You can still get Z80s: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80#Second_sources_and_derivatives , and the 8051 instruction set is also widely available.

The 16-bit instruction sets are still shipping; 68k in the form of Freescale "ColdFire", and 8086 in the form of 16-bit bootloader code that's still present on some PCs that don't boot straight through UEFI. Microsoft have only fairly recently dropped support for 16-bit Windows applications.

32-bit x86 will continue to ship in some form for as long as someone needs to run Win32 applications. That's good for at least another couple of decades.

Comment: Add to that: ARM has been around very long already. So taking over would have happened by now.

Comment: Motorola 68k is 32-bit (32-bit data and address registers).